# Difference between ably realtime Channel.off method and Channel.unsubscribe

Tags: ably-realtime

The Ably realtime javascript documentation [here](https://ably.com/documentation/realtime/channels) does not describe what the `Channel.off` method does.  I'm wondering what that method does and how it's different than `Channel.unsubscribe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relevant bit of the docs is [here](https://ably.com/documentation/realtime/channels#listening-state). The Channel object is an EventEmitter, a pattern where an object can emit named events that you can add listeners for (which is a well-known pattern in javascript, eg see nodejs's built-in EventEmitter class docs [here](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html)).

In the case of a Channel object, it emits an event whenever [the channel state](https://ably.com/documentation/realtime/channels#channel-states) changes. `Channel.off()` removes all state change listeners . (Or `Channel.off(<state>)` removes listeners for specific states, or `Channel.off(<listener>)`/`Channel.off(<state>, <listener>)` removes only a specific listener function).

The difference from `Channel.[un]subscribe(...)` is that that adds [/removes] listeners for messages published on the channel, as opposed to channel state changes.

The documentation for channels#off exists in the page source but appears to not be showing up on that page apparently due to a rendering bug.